# Recursive code not displaying the right output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following illustrative recursive code to calculate fibonacci numbers, but it is not give me the right output.

```
def fib(n):
    print("calculate f", n)

    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        print("return", n)
        return n

    print("f", n, "=", "f", (n-1), "+", "f", (n-2))

    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

n = int(input("calculate f "))
fib(n)

print("f", n, "=", n)
print("return", n)
```

When I input 2, it gives me this output:

calculate f 2

f 2 = f 1 + f 0

calculate f 1

return 1

calculate f 0

return 0

f 2 = 2

return 2

The last 2 lines of output are line though, it should be f 2 = 1 and return 1, how do I correct my code?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. What is the problem with the code? Please clarify.

Comment: You have to store the output of ``fib(n)`` if you wish to refer to it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to inflate the code with `print()`s to get the output like in the images you have provided. Now you missing `f 2 = 1` (you and images also missing `f 0 = 0` and `f 1 = 1` - not a problem I guess). The issue is solvable pretty easily since this information is available in the function `fib()`, so print it in the right place. To achieve this you need to modify the code of the function `fib()` a little bit - (1) single `return` instead of multiple, (2) keep all the `print()`s inside the function:

```
def fib(n):
    print("calculate f", n)

    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        ans = n
    else:
        print("f", n, "=", "f", (n-1), "+", "f", (n-2))
        ans = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        print("f", n, "=", ans)

    print('return', ans)
    return ans

fib(3)
```

Output:

```
calculate f 3
f 3 = f 2 + f 1
calculate f 2
f 2 = f 1 + f 0
calculate f 1
return 1
calculate f 0
return 0
f 2 = 1
return 1
calculate f 1
return 1
f 3 = 2
return 2
```

Now the output looks just like the one in the images if my eyes don't lie to me.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you have

```
print("f", n, "=", n)
```

instead of

```
print("f", n, "=", fib(n))
```

If you also want to correct the final line of code you'll want to store the return value of the fibonacci function in an intermediate value and then print it like this

```
result = fib(n)
print("f", n, "=", result)
print("return", result)
```

Comment: Tried but it didn't work. fib(n) calls itself again and gives me unwanted outputs. Output this https://imgur.com/a/52UzgNd

Comment: I see. In that case (to fix the final line) you'll want to store the result in an intermediate value and then print it out.

Comment: @YolandaHui then you need to save the result of the call to `fib(n)` so that you don't have to call it a second time.

Comment: I am stuck, is there a way to show the inner calculations too? Not just the last part. See https://imgur.com/a/OyPkaV0